# Yocto: custom Image /var/lib/dpkg missing

Tags: yocto, dpkg, package-management, yocto-wic

I am building a custom yocto image based on rocko (2.5.2) for a custom board equiped with a Xilinx Zynq7000.to generate a wic file I am usind sdimage-sota.wks.

I added debian package management in my local.conf with

```
PACKAGE_CLASSES ?= " package_deb"
EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES ?= "debug-tweaks package-management"
```

I also ran the command `bitbake package-index`.
There is no dpkg-package included in my recipes.

After building and flashing the image I get this error message: `dpkg: error: unable to access dpkg status area: No such file or directory`when I try to install a deb package.

When I extract the rootfs.tar.gz file after building, there is a `/var/lib/dpkg` directory.

If I flash the wic file to my board inside u-boot using tftpboot and mmc write there is no /var/lib/dpkg directory.

Why is the directory missing after flashing the wic file?
Is it possible, that the sdimage-sota.wks is excluding this?

Comment: You use a weak set, I would prefere to use 

    PACKAGE_CLASSES = " package_deb"

Comment: post yor bblayers.conf. Check which recipie provides dpkg ( maybe the layer do something special)

Comment: The error occurs even with ```PACKAGE_CLASSES = " package_deb" ```

Answer (score 0):

This is my bblaiers.conf:

```
# LAYER_CONF_VERSION is increased each time build/conf/bblayers.conf
# changes incompatibly
LCONF_VERSION = "7"

BBPATH = "${TOPDIR}"
BBFILES ?= ""

# These layers hold recipe metadata not found in OE-core, but lack any machine or distro content
BASELAYERS ?= " \
  ${TOPDIR}/../external/poky/meta \
  ${TOPDIR}/../external/poky/meta-poky \
  ${TOPDIR}/../external/poky/meta-yocto-bsp \
  ${TOPDIR}/../external/meta-openembedded/meta-oe \
  ${TOPDIR}/../external/meta-openembedded/meta-networking \
  ${TOPDIR}/../external/meta-openembedded/meta-webserver \
  ${TOPDIR}/../external/meta-openembedded/meta-python \
  ${TOPDIR}/../external/meta-openembedded/meta-filesystems \
  ${TOPDIR}/../external/meta-ublox-modules \
"

# These layers hold machine specific content, aka Board Support Packages
BSPLAYERS ?= " \
  ${TOPDIR}/../meta-minicate \
  ${TOPDIR}/../external/meta-updater \
  ${TOPDIR}/../external/meta-xilinx/meta-xilinx-bsp \
  ${TOPDIR}/../external/meta-rust \
  ${TOPDIR}/../external/meta-sze \
  ${TOPDIR}/../external/meta-qt5 \
"

BBLAYERS ?= " \
  ${BSPLAYERS} \
  ${BASELAYERS} \
  "
```